# python, no lena image in Image module

Tags: image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

i got a small problem with the "Lena" image from the Image module.

i want to try this code

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("lenna_face.png")
```

I can import the Image but if i try the second code it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    img = Image.open("lenna_face.png")
  File "C:\Users\Marrin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2249, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lenna_face.png'
```

how do i use the Lena image?

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/lenna.shtml

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that picture is not part of the pillow distribution. But you can download this one, and save it to your disk:

[image]

Usually this picture is called `lena.png`

Comment: I downloaded the image,  named it "lena.jpg" and put it into the folder where the .py code is saved. After that i tried the code again but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is that i have to give the path.
For example:

```
lena = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\....\lena.jpg"
img = Image.open("lena.jpg")
```

than i am able to use

```
img.show()
```

Comment: TIP: In path names on Windows, either use the normal slash (/), or escape the backslash (\\), or use raw strings: `path = r"c:\users\motoom\face.png"`